# How do I install PyQtGraph?

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot
[DEBUG] rqt_plot.plot: import of PyQtGraphDataPlot failed (trying other backends)

This is on a fresh install of U13.04 and ROS-Hydro. rqt_plot does revert back to MatPlot, but I would like to know how to install the above library, since I assume it's better. ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92046/how-do-i-install-pyqtgraph?/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.pyqtgraph.org/

Install the .deb from the site, since it's not available from the Ubuntu repositories.

Ref: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-10-17**:
Yes, that's the only way to install rqt_plot's dependency for now, due to the limitation discussed [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/103).